# how arm-thumb instruction set's blx instruction support 4MB range

Tags: assembly, arm, machine-code, thumb, instruction-encoding

Read from https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289866046.htm that arm-thumb instruction's `blx` instruction can support maximum 4MB of jump range.

But as far as I know, arm-thumb instruction is only 16 bits long, so how can 16 bits contain offset of 4MB?

Comment: ARM-Thumb is a mix of 16-bit and 32-bit instructions. `blx` is a 32-bit instruction.

Comment: initially it was two 16 bit instructions, and it remained two 16 bit instructions but latter architectures required it to be back to back instead of supporting them separately.   (granted who actually used them separately back when you could).

Comment: please refer to the arm documentation first.  the actual architecture documentation, not these assembly language manuals or other secondary documentation.  the architectural reference manuals and the technical reference manuals are the real documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original Thumb instruction set, the `BL` instruction comprised two 16 bit instructions encoded such:

```
1111 HOOO OOOO OOOO   BL <label>
     |            |
     |            \.. long branch and link offset high/low
     \............... low/high offset
                        0 -- offset high
                        1 -- offset low
```

The first of the two instructions must have the H bit set to 0.  The 11 bit offset is shifted to the left by 12, added to `PC` and placed into the `LR` register.

```
LR = PC + (offset << 12)
```

The second of the two instructions must have the H bit set to 1.  The 11 bit offset is shifted to the left by 1, added to the contents of the `LR` register, and used as a branch target.  The `LR` register is set to the return address.

```
temp = next instruction address
PC = LR + (offset << 1)
LR = temp | 1
```

With ARMv5T, a Thumb encoding of the `BLX` instruction was added, allowing Thumb code to call into ARM code.  This was done by defining a new thumb bit in the second half* of the `BL` instruction.

```
111T 1OOO OOOO OOOO   BL/BLX <label> (second half)
   |              |
   |              \.. long branch link exchange offset low
   \................. thumb bit
                        0 -- BLX is encoded
                        1 -- BL  is encoded
```

The operation of `BLX` is similar to the second half of the `BL` instruction, but the offset must be even.  The function is called in ARM state instead of Thumb state.

```
temp = next instruction address
PC = (LR + (offset << 1)) & 0xfffffffc
LR = temp | 1
CSPR T bit = 0
```

Note that with a total of 22 immediate bits giving an offset in halfwords, the observed branch offset of ±4 MiB is achieved.

Putting the two halves together, we can also see `BL` and `BLX` as 32 bit instructions with an encoding like this:

```
1111 0OOO OOOO OOOO  111T 1OOO OOOO OOOO   BL/BLX <label>
                  |     |              |
                  |     |              \.. 22 bit offset (low half)
                  |     \................. thumb bit
                  \....................... 22 bit offset (high half)
```

In Thumb2, this scheme was extended.  `BL` and `BLX` became proper 32 bit instructions and their halves must be given consecutively.<sup>†</sup>  Some bits of the second instruction word were defined to extend the branch offset to ±16 MiB.

```
1111 0SOO OOOO OOOO  11AT BOOO OOOO OOOO   BL/BLX <label>
      |           |    || |            |
      |           |    || |            \.. 21 bit offset (low half)
      |           |    || \............... additional bit J2
      |           |    |\................. thumb bit
      |           |    \.................. additional bit J1
      |           \....................... 21 bit offset (high half)
      \................................... sign bit
```

If the thumb bit is set, the `BL` instruction is encoded.  If it is clear, the `BLX` instruction is encoded.  In the latter case, the 21 bit offset must be even.  The branch offset is then computed as follows:

```
I1 = !(J1 ^ S)
I2 = !(J2 ^ S)
imm32 = (S ? 0xffff << 24 : 0) | (I1 << 23) | (I2 << 22) | (imm21 << 1)
temp = next instruction address
PC = LR + offset
LR = temp | 1
if thumb bit clear
    CSPR T bit = 0
```

While the scheme to encode the additional offset bits seems convoluted at first, it is just the simplest way to encode two additional bits into the branch offset while being compatible with the existing encoding of the `BL` and `BLX` instructions.

---

See the *ARM Architecture Reference Manual, ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition,* the *ARM7TDMI Data Sheet*, and the *ARM Architecture Reference Manual* for ARMv5 for further reading.

* The related encoding `1110 0OOO OOOO OOOO` encodes the 16 bit unconditional branch instruction `B <label>`.

† Before Thumb2, the two parts of a `BL` or `BLX` instruction were independent instructions and could be given interspersed with other instructions or even individually, though it was strongly recommended to issue them in consecutive order.  An interrupt could also occur between the two halves of a `BL` or `BLX` instruction, making the temporary contents of the `LR` register observable.  On Thumb2 targets including ARMv6-M, this is no longer possible and `BL` and `BLX` behave as a 32 bit instruction.